# unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, function, return

Here is my code:

```
signal = np.load('signal_glitches.npy')
#print(signal[:, 0])
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
print(type(signal))
def t0_t(arr, n):
    arr = list(arr)
    for i in range (n):
        if arr[i] <= np.mean(arr):
            t = int(arr.index(max(arr)))
            #print(t)
            delta_t = abs(arr.index(max(arr)) - i - 1)
            return (delta_t, t)
        break
for i in range (len(signal[:, 0])):
    ax.plot(signal[i,:], '--') 

print(len(signal[235, :]))
def exp_model(time, a, tau_0, tau_1, c):
    S = a * (1 - np.exp((time)/tau_0)) * np.exp((time)/tau_1) + c
for i in range (len(signal[:, 0])):
    arr = signal[i,:]
    n = len(signal[i,:])
    time, t = t0_t(arr, n)
    if time == None:
        time = 199
    #print(time)
ax.set_title(label = 'run7det88' + ',' + str(len(signal[:,0])) + 'glitches', y = 1.02, fontsize = 18)
plt.xlabel('ADC', fontsize = 30)
plt.ylabel('I(nA)', fontsize = 30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelsize = 18, which = 'major', pad = 18)
plt.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelsize = 18, which = 'major', pad = 18)
plt.tick_params(which = 'both', width = 3)
plt.tick_params(which = 'major', length = 8)
plt.tick_params(which = 'minor', length = 4)
#axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

and the python noticed that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-e3826bc92d95> in <module>
     21     arr = signal[i,:]
     22     n = len(signal[i,:])
---> 23     (time, t) = t0_t(arr, n)
     24     if time == None:
     25         time = 199

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I tried to print out both delta_t and t, and all of them return value, I don't know how to fix it
And I also return the integer values: 199 and 200, it still noticed the same

Comment: It sounds like the first item in `arr` is greater than the mean. This will cause the `if` to not execute taking you straight to the `break` which will implicitly return `None`.

Comment: Your function `t0_t()` is returning `None`, probably because `n` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if a function ends without a value being explicitly returned, the default return value is `None`.

For example, this code:

```
def func():
    num = 7
print(func())
```

will output `None`, as `func` did not return any value.

In your code, `t0_t` is returning `None`, which you are then trying to unpack with

```
(time, t) = t0_t(arr, n)
```

You cannot unpack a Nonetype, hence the error.

Try rewriting the function as

```
def t0_t(arr, n):
    arr = list(arr)
    for i in range (n):
        if arr[i] <= np.mean(arr):
            t = int(arr.index(max(arr)))
            #print(t)
            delta_t = abs(arr.index(max(arr)) - i - 1)
            return (delta_t, t)
        break

    return (None, None)
```

This ensures that the function will always return a 2-tuple which can be unpacked.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's possible that `t0_t` falls off the end of the function without explicitly returning something, so that Python treats it as if you had said `return None`.  You should add some more code to cover this case.

Comment: I thought so,too. But when I tried to return the determined values:199 and 200. The same problem has occured